# How to expose all methods of child component in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, composition

When wrapping third-party components, props and emits can be passed automatically with "v-bind=$attrs". How do expose of childComponent pass automatically like they do?

```
// ChildComp
<script setup lang="ts">
import { PropType } from 'vue';

defineProps({
    name:String,
    list:Array as PropType<any[]>,
})
defineEmits(['change', 'delete'])
defineExpose({
    method1:()=>{
        //...
    },
    method2:()=>{
        //...
    },
    method3:()=>{
        //...
    },
    method4:()=>{
        //...
    },
    ...
})
</script>

// MyComp
<template>
  <--! others -->
  <ChildComp v-bind="$attrs"/>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import ChildComp from './ChildComp.vue'

defineExpose({
  myMethod:()=>{ //... }
})

// method1,method2,method3,method4... of ChildComp  
// How to expose all?
</script>
```

Expose of childComponent pass automatically

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the exposed methods on the mount:

```
<template>
  <ChildComp ref="child" v-bind="$attrs"/>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
import ChildComp from './ChildComp.vue'

const child = ref();

const expose = {};
defineExpose(expose);

onMounted(()=>{
  Object.assign(expose, child.value);
});

</script>
```

Comment: An error is reported in the vite4 build environment.
I discover that the keys of child.value cannot be enumerated  in the vite4 build environment.